# How can I have a text field inside a JQuery-Button without the button fireing when going into the textfield

Tags: jquery, onclick, uibutton, textfield

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#countButton').on("click", function(){
                target=$('#until').prop("value");
                tl=(""+target).length;
                numberString="";
                for(var i=0; i<=target; i++){
                    numberString+=((""+i).padStart(tl, '0'))+"<br />";
                }
                $("#numbers").html(numberString);
            });
        });</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" id="countButton">Count from 0 to <label for="until"> <input id="until" value="20" style="width: 50px;" type="number" min="1" /> </label>!</button>
    <div id="numbers"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works quiet well, but the buttons goes off as soon as I enter the number field, is there a way to prevent it? (I know why the button goes off and I understand that I could simply move the field outside the button, but I really like this design idea. Also note (though I don't think it will make a difference to the solution) that the button might be created dynamically).

Answer (score 0):

This is because event propagation from the input field (id: until).

Just catch the event and stop propagation. See code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#countButton').on("click", function(){
                target=$('#until').prop("value");
                tl=(""+target).length;
                numberString="";
                for(var i=0; i<=target; i++){
                    numberString+=((""+i).padStart(tl, '0'))+"<br />";
                }
                $("#numbers").html(numberString);
            });
            $('#until').on("click", function(){
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        });</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all" id="countButton">Count from 0 to <label for="until"> <input id="until" value="20" style="width: 50px;" type="number" min="1" /> </label>!</button>
    <div id="numbers"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed.